# Canno't create a PySimpleGui table with my data

Tags: python, pysimplegui

**My table does not accept data in format, that I put in var **dataT****

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

dataT = [[''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['']]

def edit():

    sg.theme('Light Green 1')

    headings = ['CPF', 'NAME', 'ENDEREÇO', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'GENDER', 'EMAIL',
        'BIRTH', 'FAQ']

    # ------ Window Layout ------
    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=dataT[1:][:], headings=headings, max_col_width=55,
            auto_size_columns=True,
            display_row_numbers=True,
            justification='center',
            key='-TABLE-',
            size=(920,390))],
        [sg.Button('Delete')],
    ]

    # ------ Create Window ------
    window = sg.Window('MyTable', layout)

    # ------ Event Loop ------
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event is None:
            break

    window.close()

edit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 9 columns for headings,

```py
headings = ['CPF', 'NAME', 'ENDEREÇO', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'GENDER', 'EMAIL', 'BIRTH', 'FAQ']
```

Here table data means 9 rows and each one only with one row.

```py
dataT = [[''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['']]
```

Option `size` maybe something wrong, it said **'DO NOT USE! Use num_rows instead'**.

To avoid the width just exactly match the length of each heading, set each column width with extra 2 more chars.

Character width maybe not exactly same as shown for non-monospace font, so add monospace font by method `sg.set_options`.

After all, code as following,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

dataT = [
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
]

def edit():

    sg.theme('LightGreen1')
    sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

    headings = ['CPF', 'NAME', 'ENDEREÇO', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'GENDER', 'EMAIL',
        'BIRTH', 'FAQ']

    # ------ Window Layout ------
    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=dataT, headings=headings, max_col_width=55,
            auto_size_columns=False,
            col_widths=list(map(lambda i:len(i)+2, headings)),
            display_row_numbers=True,
            justification='center',
            key='-TABLE-',
            num_rows=20)],
        [sg.Button('Delete')],
    ]

    # ------ Create Window ------
    window = sg.Window('MyTable', layout)

    # ------ Event Loop ------
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event is None:
            break

    window.close()

edit()
```

[image]